# Get array of fields from a belongs_to association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a object User and object Post. A User has_many Posts and a Post belongs_to a User.
I can access the posts a user has using syntax like:

```
posts = @user.posts
```

However, I want to generate an array of ids of the posts a user owns, without looping through each one.  Ideally, I'd like to do this:

```
ids = @user.posts.id
```

However, I get an error, saying that id is an invalid method for ActiveRecord--etc etc...

Is there any way to neatly do this without having to do a loop like:

```
ids = []
posts = @user.posts
posts.each |post| do
   ids << post.id
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rails provides a [native method](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_many) for this:

```
@user.post_ids
```

Essentially, you can refer to the ids of a `has_many` association using `<singular association name>_ids`pattern.

Comment: this is even betrer than `pluck(:id)`

Answer (score 2):

Try with  `ids = posts.map(&:id) or ids = posts.map{|p| p.id }`

You can also try with `ids = posts.pluck(:id)`

Comment: the pluck method is the way to go, only you have to add user before posts `ids = user.posts.pluck(:id)`

Answer (score 0):

You Can also use collect.
Collect returns the Array.

```
ids = @user.posts.collect(&:id)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
@ids = @user.posts.map{|x| x.id }
```

Hope it will help.